# I'm looking for a library to create a graph that can scroll and zoom in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to make a bar chart that can display data like shown in the screenshot, with a scroll bar that can move from left to right, and zoom in or out by making it bigger or smaller.

Is there any library or tool out there that makes this much easier than starting from scratch?

[image: Bar chart with zoom]

Comment: This is well worth a read: http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/08/interactive-data-visualization-geospatial-d3-dc-leaflet-python/

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Chart for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejchart) supports creating this kind of chart and zooming can be applied to achieve your requirement.

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/jreokvrv)

[image: Chart with zooming]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Can you confirm that I could use the community edition in a product while I sell, so long as I don't have 1,000,000 revenue?

Comment: @Mawg Yes.You can use in a selling product as long as the company owning the software has less than 1 million in revenue.

Answer (score 0):

[Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) is a very good chart generator for python that generates such charts but if you are not happy with python use [Plotly](https://plot.ly/).

Plotly has APIs for Python, R, MATLAB, Excel and **Javascript**. The core JavaScript library, plotly.js, has been [Open Sourced](https://plot.ly/javascript/open-source-announcement). Browser charts have controls for panning, scrolling, zooming, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two of the most widely used free JavaScript solutions are [D3Js](https://d3js.org/) (by fat the largest) and [Chart.Js](http://www.chartjs.org/) (there are many more, and G.I.Y.F).

Example charts are [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) and [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), respectively.

It is probable that you already know of these, and are only concerned with the scroll bar, in which case, there are lots of questions, answers & examples, such as [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9689303) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854244/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-chart-js-line-chart-with-a-locked-y-axis), if you Google for them.